# Extracting div class from within another div class with jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to extract a href from a div class within another div class. One example of a code snippet i am trying to use is:

```
<div class="productData"> 
           <div class="productTitle">
            <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786866020" rel="nofollow noreferrer"> Fish! A Remarkable Way to Boost Morale and Improve Results</a> 
            <span class="ptBrand">by <a href="/Stephen-C.-Lundin/e/B001H6UE16">Stephen C.     Lundin</a>, <a href="/Harry-Paul/e/B001H9XQJA">Harry Paul</a>, <a href="/John-    Christensen/e/B003VKXJ04">John Christensen</a> and Ken Blanchard</span>
            <span class="binding"> (<span class="format">Hardcover</span> - Mar. 8, 2000)    </span>
           </div>
```

I am trying to extract the innter class productTitle from this example however using the code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(fullST).timeout(10*1000).get();
            Element title = doc.getElementById("div.productTitle");
            System.out.println(title);
```

I get null. Trying to extract higher elements such as:

```
Element title = doc.getElementById("div.productData");
```

I also get null. I have tried many code combinations but cannot figure out the syntax to extract from inner div classes or inner ids.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to select the element by ID using `getElementById()`. This is wrong. Those div's don't have an ID. Instead, they have a classname. You should use the `select()` method instead.

```
Element title = doc.select("div.productTitle").first();
```

Note that the classname selector doesn't necessarily return a single element. There can be multiple of them in the document. I assume that you need the first and the only `Element`, so I added `first()` call to the example.